# How can i set a newline in a set string in SWI-Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have this string:

```
B='Dogs cats birds and fish'.
```

and i need it to appear in the format bellow:

```
Dogs,
cats,
birds,
and fish
```

Is there any possible way for this to happen?

I tried `nl`as in:
B='Dogs,nl, cats,nl, birds,nl, and fish'.

and `\n` as in:
B='Dogs,\n, cats,\n, birds,\n, and fish'.

to no avail

B='Dogs cats birds and fish'.

Comment: Can you show how you used `nl` and `\n` here?

Comment: I tried nl as in: B='Dogs,nl, cats,nl, birds,nl, and fish'.

and \n as in: B='Dogs,\n, cats,\n, birds,\n, and fish'.

Answer (score 3):

The new line character works, you should use [**`write/1`** <sup>[swi-doc]</sup>](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=write/1) to print the string to the console, like:

```
?- write('Dogs,\ncats,\nbirds,\nand fish').
Dogs,
cats,
birds,
and fish
true.

?- B = 'Dogs,\ncats,\nbirds,\nand fish', write(B).
Dogs,
cats,
birds,
and fish
B = 'Dogs,\ncats,\nbirds,\nand fish'.
```

If you unify a variable, the Prolog will print that variable as a string literal, not the *content* of the string.

Answer (score 3):

you should split the string as a list, and then iterate the list and write.

In `Prolog`, `nl` is a **[Predicate](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nl/0)**, is can not be used like `\n`,

```
print_s([]).
print_s([H|L]):-
    write(H),
    nl,
    print_s(L).

print_s(['Dogs,', 'cats,', 'birds', 'and fish']).
```